# Why can't i dereference a pointer to struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers, visual-c++, struct

I have created one struct in C and trying to print the struct values in different ways.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<tchar.h>


#define KEY_SIZE 8
typedef struct _TREENODE {
    struct _TREENODE *Left, *Right;
    TCHAR key[KEY_SIZE];
    LPTSTR pData;
}TREENODE, *LPTNODE, **LPPTNODE;

#define NODE_SIZE sizeof(TREENODE)

int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[])

{
    LPTNODE pNode;
    TCHAR name[]="sachin tendulkar";

pNode = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, NODE_SIZE);

pNode->pData = name;

// Bothe address are same
printf("0x%p =  0x%p\n", ((char *)pNode + 16), (&((*pNode).pData)) );

//Why does it give different value ???
printf("0x%p =  0x%p\n", *((char *)pNode + 16), *(&((*pNode).pData))  );

// ERROR !!!
printf("0x%s =  0x%s\n", *((char *)pNode + 16), *(&((*pNode).pData))  );


return 0;
}
```

Below 2 codes are not working.

```
printf("0x%p =  0x%p\n", *((char *)pNode + 16), *(&((*pNode).pData))  );

printf("0x%s =  0x%s\n", *((char *)pNode + 16), *(&((*pNode).pData))  );
```

Both the below code are giving same output:

```
((char *)pNode + 16)     =    (&((*pNode).pData))
```

But below codes are not!

```
*((char *)pNode + 16)    !=   *(&((*pNode).pData))
```

Comment: `ERROR !!!` - which kind of error? Maybe you should show the actual output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Why does it give different value ???
printf("0x%p =  0x%p\n", *((char *)pNode + 16), *(&((*pNode).pData))  );
```

The addresses are the same, but the types aren't. The type of `((char *)pNode + 16)` is `char *`, so when you dereference it you get a `char`, and it just extracts the first byte of the `LPTSTR` pointer when it calls `printf()`. The type of `&((*pNode).pData)` is `*LPTSTR`, so when you dererence it you get a `LPTSTR`, so it passes the complete pointer to `printf()`.

```
// ERROR !!!
printf("0x%s =  0x%s\n", *((char *)pNode + 16), *(&((*pNode).pData))  );
```

This is the same problem. `%s` expects its argument to be a pointer to a null-terminated string. But `*((char *)pNode + 16)` is just one byte of the pointer, not the whole pointer.

Comment: thanks. This solved the problem.        printf("0x%s =  0x%s\n", *((LPTSTR *)((char *)pNode + 16)), *(&((*pNode).pData))  );